# Binding SOAP service to SAPUI5 simpleform

Tags: javascript, soap, sapui5

I have created a simple form in SAPUI5 with textviews.
I have to bind the data from SOAP service to my form. 
How to do that?
Here is the form , service.view.xml

```
<mvc:View controllerName="themes.controller.service" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:semantic="sap.m.semantic" xmlns:table="sap.m.table" xmlns="sap.m">
<Bar id="bar4">
    <contentLeft>
        <Button icon="sap-icon://nav-back" press="onNavBack"/>
        <Button icon="sap-icon://home" press="onNavBack"/>
    </contentLeft>
    <contentRight>
        <Button icon="sap-icon://account" press="handleAccount"/>
    </contentRight>
</Bar>
<Page id="pag1">
    <content>

    <f:SimpleForm id="form3" columnsL="1" columnsM="1" editable="false" emptySpanL="4" 
        emptySpanM="4" labelSpanL="3" labelSpanM="3" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" maxContainerCols="2" minWidth="1024" >
            <f:content>

                <Label text="Country"/>
                <Text text="{country}"/>
                <Label text="Phone Number"/>
                <Text text="{phone}"/>
                <Label text="Carrier"/>
                <Text text="{carrier}"/>
                <Label text="Incoterms"/>
                <Text text="{incoterms}"/>

            </f:content>
        </f:SimpleForm>
    </content>

</Page>
<Bar id="bar5">
    <contentLeft>
        <Button icon="sap-icon://email" press="handleContact"/>
    </contentLeft>
</Bar>
```

How do I work on the model creation and taking values from the SOAP service?
As I am only familiar with OData service please help me in binding the values from SOAP service

Comment: 1st: SOAP = PITA. 2nd: SAPUI5 does not support SOAP. That means you probably have to do alot of `$.ajax` calls and build an XML model with the content of the SOAP response of the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not aware of that. I still need to do this.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done fairly easy (and contrary to what Marc commented, you'll need just one `$.ajax` call) and an `sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel`:

```js
// first create your SOAP request envelope
var soapRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" + 
                  "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/\" soap:encodingStyle=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding\">" + 
                  "    <soap:Body>" + 
                  "        <m:GetPrice xmlns:m=\"http://www.w3schools.com/prices\">" + 
                  "            <m:Item>Apples</m:Item>" + 
                  "        </m:GetPrice>" + 
                  "    </soap:Body>" + 
                  "</soap:Envelope>";

// instantiate an XMLModel
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel();

$.ajax(sURL, { // sURL is the url you are sending the SOAP request to
    method: "POST",
    data: soapRequest,
    dataType: "xml",
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
}).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // in the 'done' Promise, store the SOAP response into your XMLModel
    oModel.setData(data);
}).fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
    jQuery.sap.log.fatal("The following problem occurred: " + textStatus, XMLHttpRequest.responseText + "," + XMLHttpRequest.status + "," + XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
});
```

See https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel.html for more info

Comment: Sure, in this case you need only one call.. but if your whole API is SOAP based, you'd need a proper WSDL parser and/or lots of handcoded calls to the backend, that's what I meant ;)

Comment: @Marc, you're right. And that's the biggest reason why you should never, *ever* attempt to call a SOAP service from Javascript (there is nothing in SOAP that can't be done with REST). If you really need to stick with SOAP, the OP can better call that service on a backend and present the results in a format more front-end-friendly (in other words, use REST like the JSONModel or ODataModel)