# How to consume SOAP webservice in SAP UI5?

Tags: web-services, user-interface, sapui5

I have a SOAP webservice and details of the service provided are: webservice name: "xyz", username: "Ashish", class name: "Initializer" and method name: "Fetchvalue". I have to call the method "Fetchvalue" in which an object of class "Initializer" is used as a paramter. I am developing a web app using SAP UI5, i tried a lot to call this method but not able to get a proper solution for this. Will you please tell me how can i call this method with specific requiremenst resulting in desired output from the webservice.

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798899/binding-soap-service-to-sapui5-simpleform

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible to call a SOAP method from a UI5 application, but there are no specific UI5 components to help you with that. This means that you'll just have to make do with the lower level function, either provided by jQuery or by calling XMLHttpRequest directly.

jQuery has a specific [soap plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/soap/) for this purpose, that makes calling SOAP methods quite easy:

```
$.soap({
    url: 'http://my.server.com/soapservices/',
    method: 'helloWorld',

    data: {
        name: 'Ashish Jain',
        msg: 'Hi!'
    },

    success: function (soapResponse) {
        // do stuff with soapResponse
    },
    error: function (SOAPResponse) {
        // show error
    }
});
```

Please note that the eventual call is made using XMLHttpRequest, which requires CORS headers to be setup on the server hosting your SOAP service. Alternatively, you could setup a proxy on the server that is hosting your UI5 app, that links to the server hosting the SOAP service. If you go this path, you may also want to see if you could have this proxy layer to translate SOAP into JSON for you. That would allow you to easily use a JSONModel from your UI5 app, which makes things easier and cleaner at the UI side.

Since you mentioned that you'll have to call the SOAP service using a username and password, I think a word of caution is mandatory in this answer. UI5 apps run in the browser of your end-user. This means that your end-user can have a look at your Javascript code. Hence, having a username and password in your Javascript code is bad practice. You may want to see if you can push authentication to the SOAP end-point to the proxy if possible.